# accessing concatinated javascript variables in php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

i want  to access my concatenated javascript variables in php here is my code its through ajax

```
function storeMarker(){
var lng = document.getElementById("longitude").value; 
var lat = document.getElementById("latitude").value;
//geeting the user data in form
var getVars =  "?name=" + document.getElementById("name").value
+ "&address=" + document.getElementById("address").value
+ "&description=" + document.getElementById("description").value
+ "&property_type=" + document.getElementById("property_type").value
+ "&type=" + document.getElementById("type").value
+ "&lng=" + lng
+ "&lat=" + lat ;
alert(getVars);//if i alert this its work mean all values i need from form is available

var request = GXmlHttp.create();
request.open('GET', 'storeMarker.php' + getVars, true);

}
```

now the problem is how can i access all variables in storeMarker.php through $_GET.
I want each variables as a PHP var to do other things in php page.
thanking you in anticipation

Comment: You can access them through $_GET['name'], $_GET['address'], $_GET['description'] etc.

Comment: i did it like this in php page                                         include_once('clsGeneral.php');
 $name=$_GET['name'];
$address=$_GET['address'];
$type=$_GET['type'];
$property_type=$_GET['property_type'];
$descreption=$_GET['description'];
$lat=$_GET['lat'];
$lan=$_GET['lng'];

$my_query="INSERT INTO map_marker SET name='$name',address='$address',type='$type',property_address='$property_type',descreption='$descreption',lat='$lat',lan='$lat'";
db_execute($my_query);

Answer (score 1):

You simply do this;

```
if (isset($_GET['address'];){
   $address = $_GET['address'];
}
if (isset($_GET['DESCRIPTIOM'];){
   $description= $_GET['description'];
}
```

and so on for all the others. In php you access GET variables from the $_GET associative array and POST variables from $_POST

look here for some reference: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Answer (score 1):

Please try this way:

```
<html>
      <head>
        <title>PHP Test</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            let number = 10;
            document.write(number);
        </script>  
        <?php
            $number = '<script>document.write(number);</script>';
            echo "<br>The number value is : ".$number;
        ?>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all print all parameters:

```
print_r($_GET);
```

You will see all passed parameters.

you can access parameters as:

```
$_GET['property_type']
```

or iterate through array:

```
foreach ($_GET as $k => $v) {
   if ($k == 'property_type') {
     //do something with value
   }
}
```

Comment: here is my php     <?php
include_once('clsGeneral.php');
 $name=$_GET['name'];
$address=$_GET['address'];
$type=$_GET['type'];
$property_type=$_GET['property_type'];
$descreption=$_GET['description'];
$lat=$_GET['lat'];
$lan=$_GET['lng'];

$my_query="INSERT INTO map_marker SET name='$name',address='$address',type='$type',property_address='$property_type',descreption='$descreption',lat='$lat',lan='$lat'";
db_execute($my_query); if echo t than there is no response